# How to evaluate arbitrary code in Python?

Tags: python

I'd like to be able to evaluate arbitrary code from a string in Python, including code composed of multiple statements, and statements that span multiple lines. The approaches I've tried so far have been to use `exec` and `eval`, but these seem to only be able to evaluate expressions. I have also tried the [code.InteractiveInterpreter](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html) class, but this also only seems to allow evaluation using `eval`, `exec`, or single-statement modes. I've tried splitting the code by line, but this fails to handle statements that span multiple lines. Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: No you don't want this. Because it's completely unneeded, unsafe, adds a lot of headache and is dirty anyway.

Comment: @delnan: He's not said what he's working on. There's no harm in a warning about it, but maybe he does actually want this?

Comment: @Thomas: There are cases where this (with ecxessive attention on validation and/or sandboxing, of course) is a valid approach. But they're rare and for some reason relatively many people try to use this for problems that have much better solutions. So *chances* are this is one of those cases.

Comment: @delnan: Let's give people the benefit of the doubt, at least until we know the reasoning. Anyway, it's only really unsafe in a server/client model where you have to defend against possible malicious users. If it's a program running on the user's own computer, they're free to 'hack' it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`exec` seems to be what you are looking for:

```
s = """
for i in range(5):
    print(i)
"""
exec s
```

prints

```
0
1
2
3
4
```

`eval()` only handles expressions, but `exec` handles arbitrary code.

Comment: Yes, looks like you are correct, it seems I was mistaken about exec. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Can you tell me the issue you're facing with `exec`? This seems to work for me.

```
>>> foo = """
... def baz():
...   print "Hello"
... """
>>> 
>>> exec foo
>>> baz()
Hello
>>>
```

`exec` also has an `in` form where you can insert the result of the evaluation into a namespace which is better than polluting the current one.

Answer (score 2):

Just to build on what sven is saying there is a conditional part to using exec which allows the specification of a namespace to execute inside for example when exec code in the global namespace you can do

```
exec "code" in globals()
```

or if you want to specify your own namespace hand it a dict

```
di = {}
exec "code" in di
```

Answer (score 0):

**Update for Python 3:**
Just as with `print`, `exec` now has to be used with parenthesis:

```
exec("print(1)")
```

Some things have changed in the behavior, see [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behavior-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3)