# Creating dynamically named variables in a function in python 3 / Understanding exec / eval / locals in python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

First of all, let me say that I read the many threads with similar topics on creating dynamically named variables, but they mostly relate to Python 2 or they assume you are working with classes. And yes, I read [Behavior of exec function in Python 2 and Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behaviour-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3).

I'm also aware that creating dynamically named variables is a bad idea in 99% of time and dictionaries are the way to got, but I just want to know whether it is still possible and how exactly exec and locals work in python 3.

I'd like to show a bit of sample code illustrating my question (fibonacci calculates fibonacci numbers, ListOfLetters provides ["A", "B", ...]):

```
def functionname():
    for index, buchstabe in enumerate(ListOfLetters.create_list("A", "K"), 1): 
        exec("{} = {}".format(buchstabe, fibonacci(index)) ) #A = 1, B = 1, C = 2, D = 3, E = 5,...
        print(index, buchstabe, eval(buchstabe)) #works nicely, e.g. prints "4 D 3"
    print(locals()) #pritns all locals: {'B': 1, 'A': 1, 'index': 11, 'C': 2, 'H': 21, 'K': 89, ...
    print(locals()['K']) #prints 89 as it should
    print(eval("K")) #prints 89 as it should
    print(K) #NameError: name 'K' is not defined
```

So at least at my current understanding, there is some inconsistency in the behaviour of `locals()`, since it contains the variable names added by `exec()` but the variables are not available in the function.

I would be greatful if someone could explain this and tell whether this is by design or if it is a real inconsistency in the language. Yes, I know that [`locals`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#locals) should not be modified , but I'm not modifying it, I'm calling `exec()`...

Comment: Answers from [this topic](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8028708/dynamically-set-local-variable-in-python) should really give you better understanding.

Comment: See [Behaviour of exec function in Python 2 and Python 3](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15087355); answering your question directly.

Comment: And note that `exec()` is modifying `locals()` on your behalf because you didn't pass in any more specific namespace dictionaries.

Comment: You may find [this question/answer](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7969949/208880) useful, as well.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

When you're not sure why something works the way it does in Python, it often can help to put the behavior that you're confused by in a function and then disassemble it from the Python bytecode with the `dis` module.

Lets start with a simpler version of your code:

```
def foo():
    exec("K = 89")
    print(K)
```

If you run `foo()`, you'll get the same exception you're seeing with your more complicated function:

```
>>> foo()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#167>", line 1, in <module>
    foo()
  File "<pyshell#166>", line 3, in foo
    print(K)
NameError: name 'K' is not defined
```

Lets disassemble it and see why:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(foo)
  2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (exec)
              3 LOAD_CONST               1 ('K = 89')
              6 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
              9 POP_TOP

  3          10 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (print)
             13 LOAD_GLOBAL              2 (K)
             16 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             19 POP_TOP
             20 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             23 RETURN_VALUE
```

The operation that you need to pay attention to is the one labeled "13". This is where the compiler handles looking up `K` within the last line of the function (`print(K)`). It is using the `LOAD_GLOBAL` opcode, which fails because "K" is not a global variable name, rather it's a value in our `locals()` dict (added by the `exec` call).

What if we persuaded the compiler to see `K` as a local variable (by giving it a value before running the `exec`), so it will know not to look for a global variable that doesn't exist?

```
def bar():
    K = None
    exec("K = 89")
    print(K)
```

This function won't give you an error if you run it, but you won't get the expected value printed out:

```
>>> bar()
None
```

Lets disassemble to see why:

```
>>> dis.dis(bar)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (K)

  3           6 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (exec)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 ('K = 89')
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             15 POP_TOP

  4          16 LOAD_GLOBAL              1 (print)
             19 LOAD_FAST                0 (K)
             22 CALL_FUNCTION            1 (1 positional, 0 keyword pair)
             25 POP_TOP
             26 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             29 RETURN_VALUE
```

Note the opcodes used at "3" and "19". The Python compiler uses `STORE_FAST` and `LOAD_FAST` to put the value for the local variable `K` into slot 0 and later fetch it back out. Using numbered slots is significantly faster than inserting and fetching values from a dictionary like `locals()`, which is why the Python compiler does it for all local variable access in a function. You can't overwrite a local variable in a slot by modifying the dictionary returned by `locals()` (as `exec` does, if you don't pass it a dict to use for its namespace).

Indeed, lets try a third version of our function, where we peek into `locals` again when we have `K` defined as a regular local variable:

```
def baz():
    K = None
    exec("K = 89")
    print(locals())
```

You won't see `89` in the output this time either!

```
>>> baz()
{"K": None}
```

The reason you see the old `K` value in `locals()` is explained in [the function's documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/functions.html#locals):

> Update and return a dictionary representing the current local symbol table.

The slot that the local variable `K`'s value is stored in was not changed by the `exec` statement, which only modifies the `locals()` dict. When you call `locals()` again, Python "update[s]" the dictionary with the value from the slot, replacing the value stored there by `exec`.

This is why the docs go on to say:

> **Note:** The contents of this dictionary should not be modified; changes may not affect the values of local and free variables used by the interpreter.

Your `exec` call is modifying the `locals()` dict, and you're finding how its changes are not always seen by your later code.

Comment: modifications to locals() is not garuanteed, and does actually occur in other Pythons (I think IronPython and the Jython do this, and CPython 2 does under certain circumstances).

Comment: Yes, I should state that all of the above disassembly is from Python 3.4.0. If you use a different Python version or an interpreter other than cpython you may get somewhat different results. My answer is mostly an exploration of *why* cpython 3.4 behaves the way it does. You really should not rely upon the specifics in your code.

Comment: Thanks for the disassembly!

Answer (score 5):

**On the exec/eval/locals question**

*At least on the CPython implementation* modifications to the `locals()` dictionary do not actually change the names in the local scope, which is why it's meant to be used read-only. You can change it, and you can see your changes in the dictionary object, but the actual local scope is not changed.

`exec()` takes two optional dictionary arguments, a global scope and a local scope. It defaults to `globals()` and `locals()`, but since changes to `locals()` aren't "real" outside of the dictionary, `exec()` only affects the "real" local scope when `globals() is locals()`, i.e. in a module outside of any function. (So in your case it's failing because it's inside a function scope).

The "better" way to use `exec()` in this case is to pass in your own dictionary, then operate on the values in that.

```
def foo():
    exec_scope = {}
    exec("y = 2", exec_scope)
    print(exec_scope['y'])
foo()
```

In this case, `exec_scope` is used as the global and local scope for the `exec`, and after the `exec` it will contain `{'y': 2, '__builtins__': __builtins__}` (the builtins are inserted for you if not present)

If you want access to more globals you could do `exec_scope = dict(globals())`.

Passing in different global and local scope dictionaries can produce "interesting" behavior.

If you pass the same dictionary into successive calls to `exec` or `eval`, then they have the same scope, which is why your `eval` worked (it implicitly used the `locals()` dictionary).

**On dynamic variable names**

If you set the name from a string, what's so wrong about getting the value as a string (i.e. what a dictionary does)? In other words, why would you *want* to set `locals()['K']` and then access `K`? If `K` is in your source it's not really a dynamically set name... hence, dictionaries.

Comment: modifications to `locals()` is not garaunteed, and does actually occur in other Pythons (I think IronPython and the Java Python do this).

Comment: The IronPython and Jython docs both say you shouldn't modify locals() and that it "may" not affect the interpreter state. I take "may not" to mean "doesn't except maybe in weird edge cases," but noting the possibility of differences between implementations is a good point.

Comment: I use neither so I can't say how often it works.  My point was that the effect of modifying `locals()` is not language specified -- hence the "may not" wording.

Comment: Thanks for the good answer! It was hard for me to decide who should get the +50...