# Python 3 exec assignment error

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this Python 3 code which is causing me issues:

```
def setStartingVariable(inputType, text, code = None, customErrorMessage = "Error: No error message"):
    while True:
        try:
            variable = inputType(input(text)) # Test if the inputted variable is of the right type. Keep in mind inputType is a variable, not a function.
        except BaseException: 
            print("Error! Try again!")
            continue
        err = 0 # Reset
        if code != None:
            exec(code)
        if err == 0:
            print("No error")
            return variable
        elif err == 1:
            print(customErrorMessage)
        else:
            print("Error: var err != 1 and != 0")


def inputStartingVariables():
    global wallet
    wallet = setStartingVariable(float, "Just type a number in... ", "err = 1", "-!- error message -!-")

inputStartingVariables()
```

This should cause the prompt...

`Just type a number in...`

...And it does. And if I type in something other than a float, it gives the error...

`Error! Try again!`

...And re-prompts me. So far, so good. However, if I put in a normal number, it displays...

`No Error`

...When it should display variable `customErrorMessage`, in this case being...

`-!- error message -!-`

**I originally thought** that the issue was that in the `exec()` function, `err` wasn't being treated as a global variable, but using `global err; err = 1` instead of just `err = 1` doesn't fix it.

Comment: Please provide a minimal example. In particular, either the input or its evaluation or the loop shouldn't be necessary. See also https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask.

Comment: This _is_ the stripped-down version... It shows the basic idea of what I'm trying to do while eliminating the unecessary code.

Comment: The problem with your code is that when you are testing for input  `variable = inputType(input(text))` , it is actually converting what ever you input to the inputType. So when you type a integer, it converts the number to type float.

Comment: @Digvijayad How does that cause an issue?

Comment: You want an error when the user inputs a integer,  but your input command converts the input to float, hence no error. try printing the variable after  this. `variable = inputType(input(text))` `print(variable)`. You will see what i mean

Comment: I want an error when the user inputs something that is not an integer...

Comment: '> However, if I put in a normal number, it displays...

No Error'  that's what you put in your question. So from my understanding, if I input `10` you want your custom error.

Comment: Like, I said, I want an error the the user inputs something that is _not_ an integer. That part is working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To be straight forward:**

`your err value is never changed .It is always 0`

using `exec()` doesn't change it

This changes will answer your question:

```
def setStartingVariable(inputType, text, code = None, customErrorMessage = "Error: No error message"):
    while True:
        try:
            variable = inputType(input(text)) # Test if the inputted variable is of the right type. Keep in mind inputType is a variable, not a function.
        except BaseException: 
            print("Error! Try again!")
            continue
        exec_scope = {"err" :0}
         # Reset
        if code != None:
            print ("here")
            exec(code,exec_scope)

        print (code)
        if exec_scope["err"] == 0:
            print("No error")
            return variable
        elif exec_scope["err"] == 1:
            print(customErrorMessage)
        else:
            print("Error: var err != 1 and != 0")


def inputStartingVariables():
    global wallet
    wallet = setStartingVariable(float, "Just type a number in... ", "err = 1", "-!- error message -!-")
inputStartingVariables()
```

**cause of problem:**

1.exec is a function in python3 so if you do any variable assignment in it it will not change the variable content it will only be available for the exec function

**i.e)**

```
def a():
    exec("s=1")
    print (s)
a()

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "python", line 4, in <module>
File "python", line 3, in a
NameError: name 's' is not defined
```

For more on variable assignment you can see this both question so by [martin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behaviour-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3) and [blaknight](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076883/creating-dynamically-named-variables-in-a-function-in-python-3-understanding-e)

**edit:**

```
def setStartingVariable(inputType, text, code = None, customErrorMessage = "Error: No error message"):
    global err
    while True:
        try:
            variable = inputType(input(text)) # Test if the inputted variable is of the right type. Keep in mind inputType is a variable, not a function.
        except BaseException: 
            print("Error! Try again!")
            continue

        err = 0 # Reset
        if code != None:
            exec("global err;"+code)
            print (err)
        if err == 0:
            print("No error")
            return variable
        elif err == 1:
            print(customErrorMessage)
        else:
            print("Error: var err != 1 and != 0")


def inputStartingVariables():
    global wallet
    wallet = setStartingVariable(float, "Just type a number in... ", "err = 1", "-!- error message -!-")

inputStartingVariables()
```

Comment: I thought I addressed this issue under my "**I originally thought**" section?

Comment: @Quelklef did you see the links

Comment: Did you see my section? It should work, as proven by the fact that [this code](http://pastebin.com/Fm5Uk7t7) works

Comment: Also: I'm a bit of a Python noob, so I'm having some troubles understanding your links.

Comment: @Quelklef researching will say in a moment or so

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84765/discussion-between-vignesh-kalai-and-quelklef).

Comment: OK, it works, kinda odd to me that you have to `global` it in the function, too, and not just the `exec()`

Comment: @Quelklef click the chat link you will get more insights