# Why running exec inside function fail in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Results running the code for python3:

```
------- input option 1 - exec code is executed --------
0 - for running inside function, 1 - for running in main programa: 1
option = 1
10

------- input option 0 - exec code not executed inside function ----
0 - for running inside function, 1 - for running in main programa: 0
option = 0
code inside execfunction => A = 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myexec.py", line 19, in <module>
    print(A)    
NameError: name 'A' is not defined
---------------------Code --------------------------
```

**myexec.py**

```
def execfunction(icode):
    print('code inside execfunction => %s' %(icode))
    exec(icode)

option = int(input("0 - for running inside function, 1 - for running in main programa: "))

print('option = %d' %(option))

code = 'A = 10'

if (option == 1):
    exec(code)
else:
    execfunction(code)  

print(A)
```

Comment: The code does not "fail". The variable has a different scope if the code is executed within the function. Move the print inside the function and you will see.

Comment: @MikeScotty Thats what I thought, that `A` was a local variable of the function `execfunction()` but I tried to `print(A)` and it still doesn't work, very weird. idk why.

Comment: I did like this, and still not working:

Comment: #myexec.py


def execfunction(icode):
    print('code inside execfunction => %s' %(icode))
    exec(icode)
    print(A)

option = int(input("0 - for running inside function, 1 - for running in main programa: "))

print('option = %d' %(option))

code = 'A = 10'

if (option == 1):
    exec(code)
    print(A)
else:
    execfunction(code)

Comment: Sorry I dont konw how to upgrade my code in this tool

Comment: Sorry, it seems I made an assumption w/o actually testing. Even though ``A`` is listed in ``locals()`` inside ``execfunction``, you cannot simply print it. @DavidZarebski is right with linking to [https://stackoverflow.com/a/15087355/4349415](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15087355/4349415)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really want `execfunction` to execute the function in the global scope, you can do

```
def execfunction(code):
    exec(code, globals())
```

Then, this will make the calls to `execfunction` execute in the global scope, instead of only in the local scope of the function.

For reference: https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#exec

Answer (score 0):

Is it because exec is a function in python 3 but a statement in python 2?
[Have a look at this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behavior-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3)

Comment: No, that wouldn't matter in this case. That only matters when passing exec itself as a function. E.g., `map(exec, ["a = 1", "b+=2", "c=3"])` would work in Python 3, but fails in Python 2. His issue is with scoping.

Comment: Thanks for your attention! I have read the discussion. The workaround suggested is too complicated if one wants to keep his code easy to understand.

Comment: Edward, Thanks, right, scoping. Maybe the compatibility with python3 should have been kept in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Python compiler will LOAD GLOBAL on encountering the print statement, where it fails as undefined variable 'A'. If you try to disassemble  your code [import dis], you will get to see the execution of the backend process call.

A nice and well defined explanation is given in this
[Creating dynamically named variables in a function in python 3 / Understanding exec / eval / locals in python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076883/creating-dynamically-named-variables-in-a-function-in-python-3-understanding-e)

Comment: thanks for your link! I have read the link and it seems to be too complicated for a thing that should be simple