# Evaluation of list comprehension inside functions not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, eval

Why does `eval()` of expressions with list comprehension work fine, if done outside a function, but cease to work under all circumstances, as soon as I run the same commands inside a function? *E. g.*, why does

```py
fruit = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
meat = ['chicken', 'beef', 'steak']
s = eval("[meat[k] for k, _ in enumerate(fruit)]")
print(s)
```

work,  but not

```py
def main():
    fruit = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
    meat = ['chicken', 'beef', 'steak']
    s = eval("[meat[k] for k, _ in enumerate(fruit)]")
    print(s)
    return

main();
```

?

My example is a little contrived. But it's a minimal example nonetheless. In my actual applications I use more complicated expressions, but the above demonstrates the point at which `eval()`  breaks down. I've also tried using `eval(..., globals(), locals())`, `eval(..., None, locals())`, *etc.*, But nothing seems to help.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25076883/creating-dynamically-named-variables-in-a-function-in-python-3-understanding-e

Comment: Try add `globals=locals()` to eval arguments

Comment: Try to this way: `def main(meat,fruit):
    s = eval('[meat[k] for k, _ in enumerate(fruit)]')
    print(s)
    return

fruit = ['apple', 'banana', 'cherry']
meat = ['chicken', 'beef', 'steak']
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main(meat,fruit)`

Comment: the problem is that `eval` is evaluating the expression as if it existed outside of a function, which means that the `meat` reference will be global, because the compiler cannot tag it as a free variable. just pass the `locals` as the globals, or better yet, **avoid using `eval` to begin with**

Comment: that linked duplicate isn't really a duplicate, although it is related

Comment: guys, it isn't a duplicate, I did read the other answers. @juanpa.arrivillaga The problem is, I really need to evaluate expressions, as I'm programming a kind if metacode.

Comment: @arajshree the problem with this, is that I evaluate multiple expressions, the list of variables is not known in advance.

Comment: @geckos tried `eval(..., globals=locals())`, but get `TypeError: eval() takes no keyword arguments`. Will try `eval(..., locals())` without the keyword. It worked!!

Comment: @geckos Why is this necessary for list comprehension, but not for norm expressions? _E. g._ `eval("meat[2]")` works without needing the `locals()` argument.

Comment: I don't really know for sure, but it may be something about the list comprehension having a distinct scope behavior, maybe some one can tell us :)

Comment: Yeap, generator expression has it own scope, this is why you need locals there, there is an answer here that has more information https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36616739/python-how-can-i-run-eval-in-the-local-scope-of-a-function

Comment: but why does it even sometimes work?