# Invoking functions within exec() from a class instance

Tags: python

I have an auto-generated Python code snippet which I'd like to `exec()` from within a class instance.

A simplified snippet looks like this:

```
prog = """
def func1():
  func2()

def func2():
  pass

func1()
"""

class test():
    def run(self):
        exec(prog)

test().run()   # results in NameError: name 'func2' is not defined
exec(prog)     # works
```

While `func1()` can be called in both cases, `func2` isn't found when `exec()`'ing from within the class. If I run the `exec(prog)` first, then even the `test().run()` succeeds. It seems that the previous exec call left `func2` at some place in the namespace where it can later be found when called from within the class.

Is there a simple and clean way to call such a code snippet containing several functions from within a class?

Comment: Interesting. Your code works as written in Python 2 but I get your error on Python 3. Can you confirm you are on Python 3?

Comment: Ah yes. Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15087355/5014455

Comment: Yes, i am using Python3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `exec(prog, globals())` to execute the code in the global namespace.

Comment: Thanks a lot. This does exactly what i was hoping for.

Comment: You don' t happen to know why func1() can be called in my initial approach and why only func2 was missing? Why is only func2 affected by this limitation?

Comment: func1 and func2 exist in the namespace (ie dictionary) where the execution holds. In your code it is the local namespace of function `run()`. As `func1()` is called in the same namespace, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Not that I endorse using `exec`... But declare the function name `global`:

```
prog = """
global func1, func2
def func1():
  func2()

def func2():
  pass

func1()
"""
```

Comment: Looks good. But i'd have to parse the incoming code, search for functions and add the global statement automatically. The exec(prog, globals()) approach runs the unmodified code.

Answer (score 1):

It is redundant to use exec for that.

class is itself an executable statement.

Comment: But a class does not parse and execute text strings. So, `exec` is still needed.

Comment: Yes. This is just a simplified test. In reality the code to be executed comes from somewhere else.