# Tkinter - StringVar() trace not executing command

Tags: python, tkinter

I wrote this code to be a version manager, but it doesn't execute the command `changeDir()`. Why?

https://pastebin.com/VSnhzRzF

Comment: What do you mean by doesn't execute the command?

Comment: It doesn't print the desired string

Comment: Please don't link to off-site code. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to pass a 'name' argument to `changeDir` function. And there's no exception because your statement has no effect!

Snippet to represent the problem:

```
import sys


def exec_smth():
    # execution without effect
    exec('write_smth')

    try:
        # execution with exception because of missing argument
        exec('write_smth()')
    except TypeError as error:
        # now we pass an argument
        exec('write_smth("I failed because of %s" % error )')


def write_smth(smth):
    sys.stdout.write(smth)

exec_smth()
```

Anyway, outside your `__init__` function there're no `StringVar`s at all thanks to garbage collector, so your code would fail anyway!

There're even more problems, because you never bind any of your `sv{}` to a widget and expect something in return! But ok, let's try to do things with `exec`:

```
try:
    import tkinter as tk
except ImportError:
    import Tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.entries = []

        for _ in range(5):
            exec('self.sv{} = tk.StringVar()'.format(_))
            exec('self.sv{}.trace("w", self.change_sv)'.format(_))
            exec('self.entries.append(tk.Entry(self, text="", textvariable=self.sv{}))'.format(_))

        for entry in self.entries:
            entry.pack()

    def change_sv(*args):
        # get id of a variable (you can't rely on that (0-9)!)
        idx = args[1][-1:]
        # get new value
        value = getattr(args[0], 'sv{}'.format(idx)).get()
        # result
        print('Value changed in self.sv%s to %s!' % (idx, value))

app = App()
app.mainloop()
```

Output:

[image: output]

As you see - we always need a reference to StringVars and I think that option with a list of them is far better!

*Note: If you need to pass something to callback function - use a `lambda` function! All code tested with Python 3.*

Links:

- [The Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm)
- [Tkinter Callbacks](http://effbot.org/zone/tkinter-callbacks.htm)
- [Behavior of exec function in Python 2 and Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behavior-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3)