# Object is not being defined outside the loop in python

Tags: python, class, object, encapsulation

```
import json

xyz={"john": """{"name": "john","id":"123"}""","tom" : """{"name":"tom","id":"456"}"""}

class abc(object):
  def __init__ (self,**d):
    self.name=d['name'];
    self.id=d['id'];

def main():
   ks=xyz.keys()
   for j in ks:
      lm1="xyz['%s']" %(j)
      ds=eval(lm1);
      ds1=json.loads(ds)
      ln="%s=abc(**ds1)" %(j)
      print(ln)
      exec(ln);
      ln2="%s.name" %(j)
      print(eval(ln2));
   print(john.name)
   print(tom.id)

if __name__ == "__main__":
   main();
```

and the error is

```
tom=abc(**ds1)
tom
john=abc(**ds1)
john
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "new6.py", line 26, in <module>
    main();
  File "new6.py", line 22, in main
    print(john.name)
NameError: name 'john' is not defined
```

why am i not being able to access "tom.name","john.name" in main() block?
where did i do wrong? and how can it be done in much simpler way?
(i actually have a json file, dont bother much about the "xyz")

Comment: @khelwood error in putting up the question...its my first time

Comment: For me the program works fine as it is. No NameError if I run it.

Comment: May be because,you might be running it in python2.* ,i want it in 3.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior of this program is different between Python2.* and Python3*.

1.) `xyz.keys()` gives a `list` in Python2.7, but needs to be cast from the `dict_keys` class to a `list` in Python3.6.

2.) The behavior of `exec` is different between Python2.* and Python3.* [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behavior-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3) for more details. Because of this, if you're running your program with Python3, `john` and `tom` haven't been defined, and you get an error when trying to access them.