# Importing module in exec-statement in python

Tags: python, import, exec, nameerror

I try to import a module with *exec("import __ as tmp")* in python:

```
def prepare(self):
    for modName in self._config.modules.keys():
        print(locals())
        exec("import {} as tmp".format(modName))
        print(locals())
        self._moduleInst[modName] = tmp
```

Output is:

```
{'modName': 'time', 'self': <pyo.Server.Server object at 0x000001CA17DFB550>}
{'modName': 'time', 'self': <pyo.Server.Server object at 0x000001CA17DFB550>, 'tmp': <module 'time' (built-in)>}

Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "[...]", line 3, in <module>
        startServer(None)
    File "[...]", line 10, in startServer
        server.prepare()
    File "[...]", line 15, in prepare
        self._moduleInst[modName] = tmp
NameError: name 'tmp' is not defined
```

I get an NameError exception, cause python cannot find tmp. If I print out all local variables, tmp is defined...

Has anybody an idea what I'm doing wrong? Thank you!

Comment: Edit: If I try the same in console it works outside a function, but in a function the same error happends...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Behavior of exec function in Python 2 and Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behavior-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3)

Answer (score 0):

You don't declare `tmp` variable anywhere in your function code:

```
def prepare(self):
    for modName in self._config.modules.keys():
        print(locals())
        exec("import {} as tmp".format(modName))
        print(locals())
        self._moduleInst[modName] = vars()['tmp']
```

The *tmp* in your exec statement is a *string*. So I guess what you are trying to do is this: `self._moduleInst[modName] = 'tmp'`, which saves the string `tmp` to your dict.

Comment: I want to save a reference to the imported module, but in yout solution I "only" save a string, but no module reference.

Comment: I resolved the problem temp with this solution:

self._moduleInst[modName] = locals()["tmp"]

Comment: If that's the case, you should use vars() to print the dict. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I seem unable to reproduce this. My code:

```
class foo:
    modules = { 'string' : 0 }

    def prepare(self):
        for modName in self.modules.keys():
            print(locals())
            exec("import {} as tmp".format(modName))
            print(locals())
            self.modl = tmp

somevar = foo()
somevar.prepare()
print(somevar.modl.digits)
```

Output:

```
{'modName': 'string', 'self': <__main__.foo instance at 0x7f5c11123128>}
{'tmp': <module 'string' from '/usr/lib/python2.7/string.pyc'>, 'modName': 'string', 'self': <__main__.foo instance at 0x7f5c11123128>}
0123456789
```

Difference in Python versions?

Comment: I use Python 3.6.2 (v3.6.2:5fd33b5). With Python 2.7 I have no problems. Maybe it's an bug in python..?