# Modules imported using `exec` are not available if imported by a function

Tags: python, python-import

In Python 3, when I import a module using `exec` in the global scope, it works. But when I do it within a function, even though I get no import error, Python does not recognize the module name.

Importing and **using** `sys` successfully, in the global scope:

```
>>> sys.argv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'sys' is not defined
>>> exec('import sys')
>>> sys.argv
['']
```

No import error, though cannot use `os` which has been imported from a function:

```
>>> def import_os():
...   exec('import os')
...   os.listdir('.')
...
>>> import_os()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 3, in import_os
NameError: name 'os' is not defined
>>>
```

Any idea how to make this work from within a function?

Comment: Why would you do this? If you want to import things dynamically, use `importlib`.

Comment: FWIW `exec('import os', globals())` makes it work.

Comment: thank you guys. I really used `importlib` and `getattr` eventually (needed to import a specific function from some module)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Behavior of exec function in Python 2 and Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behavior-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3)