# Python Exec Command Won't Define Object

Tags: python, class, oop

The following code:

```
exec(str(newName) + " = Leagues('"+str(name)+"','" + str(ldata[2]) + "'," + str(teams) + "," + str(len(teams)) + "," + str(ldata[3]) + "," + str(ldata[4]) + "," + str(ldata[5]) +")")
```

Runs without a syntax error however does not carry out its purpose (define an object of a class, "Leagues").

The code operates in a loop so it essentially looks like this (without the array indexing and breaks in the speech marks):

```
exec("EnglishDivision1 = Leagues('English Division 1','England',[#an array],20,4,3,3)")
```

The code above runs but does not actually create an object. However, when I enter this exact code without the exec command, it works just fine and an object is created. Anyone know what's going on?

Comment: I think this is a namespace issue with `exec`.  Note that `exec` is *very* different between Python 2 and Python 3, but from your post I assume you're using Python 3.  I'm including a previous answer that may help (look at Martijn's answer).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Behavior of exec function in Python 2 and Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behavior-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3)

Comment: By the way, a better way to do this is to keep your values in a `dict`, which will allow you to avoid the use of `exec` altogether.

Comment: The code works while not in a function, why does this happen? Is this a namespace error?

Comment: When not in a function, it uses the global namespace for the assignment.