# What happened when invoking locals() in python3?

Tags: python-3.7

I'm using Python3.7.2

The code which makes me confused looks like this:

```
def foo(cond):
    if cond:
        z = 1
        return z
    else:
        loc = locals()
        x = 1
        locals()['y'] = 2
        exec("z = x + y")
        print(loc)
        print(locals())

foo(False)
```

Here is the result it prints:

```
{'cond': False, 'loc': {...}, 'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
{'cond': False, 'loc': {...}, 'x': 1, 'y': 2}
```

The exec function changes the local namespace, but when I execute locals(), variable z disappeared.

However, if I change the code like this:

```
def foo(cond):
    if cond:
        return 1
    else:
        loc = locals()
        x = 1
        locals()['y'] = 2
        exec("z = x + y")
        print(loc)
        print(locals())

foo(False)
```

The result will be:

```
{'cond': False, 'loc': {...}, 'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
{'cond': False, 'loc': {...}, 'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```

I'm really confused. :(

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behavior-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In short: the dictionary returned by `locals()` is only a *copy* of the true local variables—which are stored in an array, not in a dictionary.  You can manipulate the `locals()` dictionary, add or remove entries at will.  Python does not care since that is merely a copy of the local variables it works with.  However, each time you call `locals()`, Python copies the current values of all local variables into the dictionary, replacing anything else you or `exec()` put in before.  So, if `z` is a proper local variable (as in the first, but not second version of your code), `locals()` will restore its current value, which happens to be "not set" or "undefined".

---

Indeed, conceptually Python stores local variables in a dictionary, which can be retrieved through the function `locals()`.  However, internally, it really is two arrays.  The names of the locals are an attribute of the code itself and therefore stored in the code object as `code.co_varnames`.  Their values, however, are stored in the *frame* as `fast` (which is inaccessible from Python code).  You can find more on `co_varnames` etc. in [`inspect`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html) and [`dis`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/dis.html) modules, respectively.

The built-in function `locals()` actually calls a method [`fastToLocals()`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/a871f692b4a2e6c7d45579693e787edc0af1a02c/Objects/frameobject.c#L1070) on the current *frame* object.  If we were to write the frame with its `fastToLocals` method in Python, it might look like this (I am leaving out *a lot* of details here):

```py
class frame:
    def __init__(self, code):
        self.__locals_dict = None
        self.f_code = code
        self.__fast = [0] * len(code.co_varnames)

    def fastToLocals(self):
        if self.__locals_dict is None:
            self.__locals_dict = {}
        for (key, value) in zip(self.f_code.co_varnames, self.__fast):
            if value is not null:             # Remember: it's actually C-code
                self.__locals_dict[key] = value
            else:
                del self.__locals_dict[key]   # <- Here's the magic
        return self.__locals_dict

def locals():
    frame = sys._getframe(1)
    frame.fastToLocals()
```

In plain English: the dictionary you get when calling `locals()` is cached in the current frame.  Calling `locals()` repeatedly will give you the same dictionary (`__locals_dict` in the code above).  However, each time, you call `locals()`, the frame will update the entries in this dictionary with the current values that local variables have at that time.  As noted [here](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/2f172d8f1525defe9bba4d49e967fdfc69151731/Objects/frameobject.c#L1016), when a local variable is not set, the entry in the `__locals_dict` *is deleted*.  And that's what it is all about.

In your first version of the code, the third line says `z = 1`, which makes `z` a local variable.  In the `else` branch, however, that local variable `z` is not set (i.e. would raise a `UnboundLocalError`) and is therefore removed from the `__locals_dict`.  In the second version of your code, there is no assignment to `z`, so it is *not* a local variable and the `locals()` function does not care about it.

The set of local variables is actually fixed by the compiler.  This means that you cannot add or remove local variables at runtime.  This is a problem for `exec()`, as you are clearly using `exec()` here to define a local variable `z`.  Python's way out is to say that `exec()` stores `z` as a local variable in the `_locals_dict` dictionary, although it cannot put it into the arrays behind this dictionary.

*Conclusion:*  The values of local variables are actually stored in an array, not in the dictionary returned by `locals()`.  When calling `locals()`, the dictionary is updated with the true current values taken from the dictionary.  `exec()`, on the other hand, can only store its local variables in the dictionary, not in the array.  If `z` is a proper local variable, it will be overwritten by a call to `locals()` with its current value (which is "does not exist").  If `z` is not a proper local variable, it will stay in the dictionary untouched.

---

Python's specifications say that any variable that you assign to inside a function is a local variable.  You can change this default through the use of `global` or `nonlocal`, of course.  But as soon as you write `z = ...`, `z` becomes a local variable.  If, on the other hand, you only have `x = z` in your code, the compiler assumes that `z` is rather a global variable.  That's why the line `z = 1` makes all the difference: it marks `z` as a local variable that receives its place in the `fast` array.

Concerning `exec()`: in general, there is no way the compiler could really know what code `exec()` is going to execute (in your case with a string literal it could, but since this is a are rare and uninteresting case, it never tries, anyway).  The compiler can therefore not know what local (or global) variables the code in `exec()` might access, and cannot include that in its calculation of how large the array of local variables should be.

---

By the way: that local variables are managed in arrays instead of proper dictionaries is the reason why there might be raised an `UnboundLocalError` instead of an `NameError`.  In case of local variables, the Python interpreter actually recognises the name and knows exactly where its value is to be found (inside the `fast` array mentioned above).  But if that entry is `null`, it cannot return something meaningful and therefore raises the `UnboundLocalError`.  For global names, however, Python goes really searched for a variable with the given name in the globals and built-in dictionaries.  In that case, a variable of the requested name might *truly* not exist.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer sincerely. I'm not faimiliar with the frame object, the array which stored local variables or the `fastToLocals()` function, but your answer is intuitive and detailed, which makes me benefit a lot.

Comment: @yuryqwer You are most welcome.  I think you asked a very interesting and valid question!

Comment: Concerning frames: functions themselves are quite immutable entities (the function `foo` itself in your code never really changes--it is always the same function).  _Frames_ are thus the containers that hold the actual values for all local variables, parameters, and a pointer to where to return to after the function has finished.  It is a bit similar to how _instances_ hold the actual data as described by a _class_.  The frames also make up the _call stack_ that becomes visible in a _traceback_.  It might therefore be worth reading up on frames.

Comment: The array `fast` that stores the local variables, or the function `fastToLocals()`, on the other hand, are implementation details: you can be an outstanding Python programmer without ever worrying about it.  Nonetheless, if you are interested in that, Python's `dis` module to disassemble your code is probably the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Compare your code with the following:

```py
def foo(cond):
    if cond:
        return 1
    else:
        loc = locals().copy()
        # ——————————————^
        x = 1
        locals()['y'] = 2
        exec("z = x + y")
        print(loc)
        print(locals())

foo(False)
```

It produces

```
{'cond': False}
{'cond': False, 'loc': {'cond': False}, 'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}
```

as you might expect. The reason is that `locals()` is a reference, not a value.

Comment: That’s useful, but still can't explain why variable `z` disappeared in another example.

Comment: As you can see, if the variable `z` was declared in the `if` branch, then after the statement`exec(z = x + y)`, when we print`locals()`, we can't get the variable `z`.However, if the `if` branch doesn't mention variable `z`, we can see `{'cond': False, 'x': 1, 'y': 2, 'z': 3}` after printing `locals()`

Comment: I don't have the answer yet. However, in the first example, `locals() is loc` is `True` at the end of the function. Secondly, when I run it with a debugger, I see no `z` appearing. My best guess is the `gc` work. I can't get a proof of it, though.

Comment: Oh, it gets even funnier! `loc` in `... else: x = 1; loc = locals(); z = x; print(loc); print(locals()); print(loc is locals())` knows nothing about `z` although it is defined. `locals()` knows about `z` and `loc` as if `loc` became a new object. However, `loc is locals()` is still `True`. No `exec` involved.

Comment: `loc` and `locals()` always point the same object. The key is to find out what happens when executing the `locals` function and why `gc` delete the variable `z` when `z` was declared in the if branch, assuming the `gc` works is true.

Comment: @yuryqwer, why `('z' in loc) != ('z' in locals())` after `exec` call then? I can `import gc; gc.disable()` but this does not change a bit.

Comment: Maybe the function`locals` doesn't just return the dict, but collect something and then do some update or delete things to the dict. However, if u just use loc, such things won't happen bcause it's just a reference of the dict. Better read the source code of `locals()`.