# Python NameError in a function body

Tags: python, nameerror, python-exec

I have two blocks of python code, one works, and the other doesn't.

---

**Working block:**

```
env = {'user':'xyz'}
for key, value in env.items():
    exec("{} = value".format(key))

print(user)
```

**output:**

> *xyz*

---

**The block, which doesn't work:**

```
def test():
    env = {'user':'xyz'}
    for key, value in env.items():
        exec("{} = value".format(key))

    print(user)

test()
```

**output:**

> *NameError: name 'user' is not defined*

---

The only difference I see is that the first block is being called in the global scope.

Could you please explain?

Many thanks!

PS: With all due respect, I know, I should avoid using exec() but what if I want to.

Comment: The global scope is just a dictionary, and can be modified by `exec` or various other means.  But the local scope of a function is carved in stone at the time the function was compiled (all references get turned into an index into an array), there's no way to add names at runtime.

Comment: @jasonharper thanks, if I print locals(), it confirms the presence of this variable:{'env': {'user': 'xyz'}, 'key': 'user', 'value': 'xyz', 'user': 'xyz'}. What are your thoughts?

Comment: As said above, it shows in locals() and also in the debugger, it shows up as a variable. Why does that happen? https://i.imgur.com/Ry1xoDX.png When I try to access it on the next line, it raises exception.

Comment: if you really need to use `exec()` then use it - but I would rather keep it as dictionary `env['user'] = ...` because it can be more useful then creating variables `user = ...`

Comment: @furas the whole point of discussion is that I am not able to use exec()

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behavior-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3)

You have to use `locals()` or `exec` or `eval` to access variables defined by `exec` in a function in Python3.

```
def test():
    env = {'user': 'xyz'}
    for key, value in env.items():
        exec("{} = value".format(key))
    exec("print(user)")
    print(locals()['user'])
    print(eval("user"))
 
test()
```

It should be noted that, if you attempt to store value returned from `eval`. You will get NameError.

```
def test():
    env = {'user': 'xyz'}
    for key, value in env.items():
        exec("{} = value".format(key))
    user = eval("user")
    print(user)

test()
```

returns

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Git/sscgc/test.py", line 8, in <module>
    test()
  File "D:/Git/sscgc/test.py", line 5, in test
    user = eval("user")
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'user' is not defined
```

Comment: I had similar findings!! Thanks, @david190810 for sharing the article. It was helpful