# How to return a sub-function with variable arguments / exec() a definition inside another function ? (Python 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, exec

I have a `foo` function that returns a value that is then used as input in a `bar` function. In short, `baz = bar(foo(•), •)`.

Now, as I want to test multiple `foo` iterations with a `bar` that stays the same, I created the `make_baz` function in order to return `baz` depending on the iteration. (i.e. `baz_i = bar(foo_i(•), •)`, etc.)

The arguments and keywords are not always the same and I can not simply pass a dictionary as I am using [scipy.optimize.curve_fit](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.curve_fit.html).

I have found a way to theoretically do what I want (see below), but it seems I can not define a function with `exec` inside another function (it works as expected while in global)..

```
def foo_1(x, arg1, arg2, kwarg1=None):
    y = "some function of x"
    return y

def foo_2(x, arg1, kwarg1=None, kwarg2=None):
    y = "some other function of x"
    return y

def bar(y, bar_arg):
    z = "function of y"
    return z

def make_baz(foo):
    args = list(inspect.signature(foo).parameters)
    args_str = ", ".join(args)
    kwargs_str = ", ".join([f"{arg}={arg}" for arg in args])
    baz = f"def baz({args_str}, bar_arg):\n" \
          f"    y = {foo.__name__}({kwargs_str})\n" \
          f"    return bar(y=y, bar_arg=bar_arg)\n"
    exec(baz)
    return baz

print(make_baz(foo_1))
print(make_baz(foo_2))
```

**Problem:** it returns strings and not actual functions.

```
"""
def baz(x, arg1, arg2, kwarg1, bar_arg):
    y = foo(x=x, arg1=arg1, arg2=arg2, kwarg1=kwarg1)
    return bar(y=y, bar_arg=bar_arg)
"""
"""
def baz(x, arg1, kwarg1, kwarg2, bar_arg):
    y = foo(x=x, arg1=arg1, kwarg1=kwarg1, kwarg2=kwarg2)
    return bar(y=y, bar_arg=bar_arg)
"""
```

**Question:** do you have any workaround/solution ?

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been found on [Behavior of exec function in Python 2 and Python 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15086040/behavior-of-exec-function-in-python-2-and-python-3), defining `loc = locals()` and adding it as a parameter for `exec`:

```
def make_baz(foo):
    args = list(inspect.signature(foo).parameters)
    args_str = ", ".join(args)
    kwargs_str = ", ".join([f"{arg}={arg}" for arg in args])
    baz = f"def baz({args_str}, bar_arg):\n" \
          f"    y = foo({kwargs_str})\n" \
          f"    return bar(y=y, bar_arg=bar_arg)\n"
    loc = locals()
    exec(baz, globals(), loc)
    return loc["baz"]
```

**EDIT:** in order for the `exec` to recognize `bar`, we have to add `globals()` as argument.